# How do I fit 2 items in a 3 column android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

Currently, my gridlayout contains 2 columns. I want it to contain 3 columns so I can fit buttons on a couple of the rows, but leave the rest of the rows with only 2 objects. I have pasted one of the rows in the code below. I only want these 2 objects on this row, but can't figure out a way to dedicate the first column to the imageview and the remaining 2 columns to the edittext .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    app:columnCount="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/location_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="32dp"
        android:maxWidth="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp" />

    <!--  Location Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locationEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/material_text_body1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
            android:hint="Location"
            android:textColorHint="@color/primary_light"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: This is not a gridview. its a gridlayout (This was in a reply to someone.....)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

for `GridView`: increase column to 3: `app:columnCount="2"`

for `ImageView`: add `app:layout_column="0"`

for `TextInputLayout`, add

```
app:layout_columnSpan="2"
app:layout_column="1"
```

Hope this helps.